# Creating Powershell menu Item and calling functions in the menu item

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am trying to combine the below snippets into the existing code for updating user AD attributes.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'

Do
{
    Write-Host -Object 'Enter a sAMAccountName / Alias "First.Lastname", or nothing (Press Enter) to leave; wildcards and a space separated list are NOT supported.' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    $UserInput = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter the User AD account to check', 'sAMAccountName / Alias "First.Lastname"', $UserInput)
    
    If ($UserInput)
    {
        $(ForEach ($Username in $UserInput.Split(' ', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                If ($ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { samAccountName -like $UserName } -Properties DisplayName)
                {
                    Write-Verbose -Message "Processing $($ADUser.DisplayName)"
                    Write-Host "The sAMAccountName $($UserInput) matching to the AD account '$($ADUser.DisplayName)'" -ForegroundColor Green
                    
                    
                    
                }
                Else
                {
                    Write-Host "Could not find a user with a sAMAccountName matching '$($UserName)' !" -ForegroundColor Red | Write-Warning
                }
            })
    }
}
Until (-not $UserInput)
```

The snippets above are working for validating user input against the Active Directory user account, to see if the AD account is valid or not.

This is the main menu item code which is used for updating the AD attributes based on the https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/recipient-type-values/7c2620e5-9870-48ba-b5c2-7772c739c651

```
# Set The attributes value for Remote Regular User Mailboxes
$replace = @{
      msExchRemoteRecipientType = 4
      msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
      msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 2147483648
}

# Set The attributes value for Remote Shared Mailboxes
$replace = @{
      msExchRemoteRecipientType = 100
      msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
      msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 34359738368
}
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser -Replace $replace -WhatIf
```

This is the main menu item code, but without the input check validation section:

```
If (!(Get-Module "*ActiveDirectory*")) {
    Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch { Write-Warning "Unable to load Active Directory module because $($Error[0])"; Exit }
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
$Input = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter the User AD account to check', 'sAMAccountName / Alias "First.Lastname"', $Input)

$properties = 'Name,msExchRemoteRecipientType,msExchRecipientDisplayType,msExchRecipientTypeDetails,proxyAddresses' -split ','
$ADUserAttributesValues = Get-ADUser -identity $Input -Properties $properties |
                            Select-Object Name,
                                          msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                                          msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                                          msExchRecipientTypeDetails

$menuCaption = "Hybrid AD User account Exchange attribute modification"
$menuMessage = "Please select the action to be applied to the user $($Input) `n $($ADUserAttributesValues)"
        ## Format: "Menu Text" = "Help Text"
        ## "Menu Text" must match the options in the Switch statement below
        ## "&" marks the character to use as hotkey

$menu = [ordered]@{
    'Remote &Shared Mailbox' = "Convert $($Input) as Remote Shared Mailbox"
    'Remote &User Mailbox'   = "Convert $($Input) as Remote User Mailbox"
    '&Quit'                  = 'Leave without changes'
}

$menuChoices = @()
$menu.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    $choice = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]$_
    $choice.HelpMessage = $menu[$_]
    $menuChoices += $choice
}

$answer = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($menuCaption , $menuMessage , $menuChoices, ($menu.Count - 1))
Switch ($menuChoices[$answer].Label) {
    'Remote &Shared Mailbox' {
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "You selected to convert $($Input) as Remote Shared Mailbox" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        # Set The attributes value for Remote Shared Mailboxes
        $replace = @{
            msExchRemoteRecipientType = 100
            msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
            msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 34359738368
        }
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.Name -Replace $replace -WhatIf
        
        # Check the attributes value
        Get-ADUser -identity $Input -Properties $properties |
            Select-Object Name,
                          msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                          msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                          msExchRecipientTypeDetails,
                          (@{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }})
    }
    'Remote &User Mailbox' {
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "You selected to convert $($Input) as Remote User Mailbox" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        # Set The attributes value for Remote Regular User Mailboxes
        $replace = @{
            msExchRemoteRecipientType = 4
            msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
            msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 2147483648
        }
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.Name -Replace $replace -WhatIf
        
        # Check the attributes value
        Get-ADUser -identity $Input -Properties $properties |
            Select-Object Name,
                          msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                          msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                          msExchRecipientTypeDetails,
                          (@{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }})
    }
    default {
        Write-Host 'Goodbye' -ForegroundColor Green
        Exit
    }
}
```

So how to combine it to the above?

The code above was created as a rough menu item with lots of repetitions, but it works. I believe it can be optimized by creating functions, but not sure how since the attributes are different.

Comment: Without having read all this yet, you should not use a variable called `$Input`, because that is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input). Use a different name for that.

Comment: Hi @Theo, thanks for the quick update. I have updated it accordingly, the snippets working just fine, it is no just a matter of creating the functions / optimizing the Menu Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine the code snippets using helper functions, here's an idea for you:

```
if (!(Get-Module "*ActiveDirectory*")) {
    Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch { Write-Warning "Unable to load Active Directory module because $($Error[0])"; Exit }
}

# function to ask the user which user to update.
# returns either a valid AD including mailbox attributes user or nothing at all
function Prompt-User {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
    # enter an endless loop
    while ($true) {
        Clear-Host
        $msg = "Enter the User AD account to check.`r`n`r`nWildcards and a space separated list are NOT supported."
        Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor Yellow

        $account = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, 'sAMAccountName / Alias "First.Lastname"')

        # exit the function if the user entered nothing or whitespace only
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($account)) { return }

        $properties = 'DisplayName','msExchRemoteRecipientType','msExchRecipientDisplayType','msExchRecipientTypeDetails'

        $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '$account'" -Properties $properties -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($ADUser) {
            Write-Host "The sAMAccountName $($account) matches the AD account '$($ADUser.DisplayName)'" -ForegroundColor Green
            return $ADUser
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Could not find a user with a sAMAccountName matching '$($account)' ! Please try again."
        }
    }
}

# function to ask the user what action to undertake
function Prompt-Action ([Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]$ADUser) {
    $menuCaption = "Hybrid AD User account Exchange attribute modification"
    $menuMessage = "Please select the action to be applied to the user $($ADUser.Name)"
            ## Format: "Menu Text" = "Help Text"
            ## "Menu Text" must match the options in the Switch statement below
            ## "&" marks the character to use as hotkey

    $menu = [ordered]@{
        'Remote &Shared Mailbox' = "Convert $($Input) as Remote Shared Mailbox"
        'Remote &User Mailbox'   = "Convert $($Input) as Remote User Mailbox"
        '&Quit'                  = 'Leave without changes'
    }

    $menuChoices = $menu.Keys | ForEach-Object {
        $choice = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]$_
        $choice.HelpMessage = $menu[$_]
        $choice
    }

    $answer = $host.UI.PromptForChoice($menuCaption , $menuMessage , $menuChoices, ($menu.Count - 1))

    return ($menuChoices[$answer].Label -replace '&')  # removing the '&' makes processing later easier
}

# function to display users Mailbox attributes
function Get-UserMailboxDetails ([string]$DistinguishedName) {
    $properties = 'msExchRemoteRecipientType','msExchRecipientDisplayType','msExchRecipientTypeDetails','proxyAddresses'
    Get-ADUser -Identity $DistinguishedName -Properties $properties -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                  msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                  msExchRecipientTypeDetails,
                  @{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {
                    ($_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') } | 
                    Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }}
}

# checks the current user mailbox type
# returns 'Remote User Mailbox', 'Remote Shared Mailbox' or 'Other'
function Check-MailboxAttributes ([Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]$ADUser) {
    if ($ADUser.msExchRemoteRecipientType -eq 4 -and 
        $ADUser.msExchRecipientDisplayType -eq -2147483642 -and 
        $ADUser.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq 2147483648) { 'Remote User Mailbox' }
    elseif (
        $ADUser.msExchRemoteRecipientType -eq 100 -and
        $ADUser.msExchRecipientDisplayType -eq -2147483642 -and
        $ADUser.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq 34359738368) { 'Remote Shared Mailbox' }
    else { 'Other' }
}

# this is your main code
do {
    $ADUser = Prompt-User
    if ($ADUser) {
        Clear-Host
        # here is where you process the user
        $action = Prompt-Action $ADUser
        if ($action -like 'Remote*') {  # either 'Remote Shared Mailbox' or 'Remote User Mailbox'
            # do we need to convert the user mailbox type?
            if ((Check-MailboxAttributes $ADUser) -eq $action) {
                Write-Host "$($ADUser.DisplayName) is already a $action" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "You selected to convert $($ADUser.DisplayName) as $action" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                if ($action -match 'User') { 
                    # create hashtable for Remote Regular User Mailboxes
                    $newProperties = @{ 
                        msExchRemoteRecipientType  = 4
                        msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
                        msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 2147483648
                    }
                } 
                else { 
                    # create hashtable for Remote Shared Mailboxes
                    $newProperties = @{
                        msExchRemoteRecipientType  = 100
                        msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
                        msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 34359738368
                    }
                }
                $ADUser | Set-ADUser -Replace $newProperties
                # reload the user and show the resulting mailbox properties
                Get-UserMailboxDetails $ADUser.DistinguishedName
            }
        }
    }
} until (-not $ADUser)

# all done
Write-Host 'Goodbye' -ForegroundColor Green
```

<sup>I agree with [postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote) that I would create a proper GUI for this rather than using Write-Host stuff in the console</sup>

Comment: Hi @Theo, thank you for the support in this thread, however, the user prompt still keep on looping in the function Prompt-User despite I have selected or typed the existing AD user.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Sorry, I left a testing variable name in there.. Updated my answer.

Comment: yes, you are right and it works great.
Thank you very muchly.

Answer (score 2):

It is a best practice for Functions to do one thing and one the well.
You then assign the function to your UI design objects.

As for the first part of your post. You cannot do this...

```
Write-Host "Could not find a user with a sAMAccountName matching '$($env:USERNAME)' !" -ForegroundColor Red | Write-Warning
```

... it will only return the red text never the warning at all.

Write-Host clears the buffer and thus cannot be used to send results down the
pipeline.

Also, you are literally calling for two warnings for the same code line/string text (one in a red color then the default Write-Warning cmdlet color). So, that's not a thing.

The Write-Warning cmdlet already generates a default color for it, which you cannot change directly. So, just use this...

```
Write-Warning -Message "Could not find a user with a sAMAccountName matching '$($Username)' !"
```

... or you have to create your own function to handle colorized text, leveraging stuff like this...

```
# Colors in the consolehost
$host.UI.RawUI
$host.PrivateData
$host.PrivateData.ConsolePaneTextBackgroundColor
$host.PrivateData.ConsolePaneForegroundColor

# In the ISE
$host.UI.RawUI
[enum]::GetNames([System.ConsoleColor])
$psise.Options.ConsolePaneForegroundColor

# Using .Net
[System.Windows.Media.Colors]
[System.Windows.Media.Colors]::White
[enum]::GetNames([System.ConsoleColor])
[enum]::GetNames([System.ConsoleColor])[0]
$psise.Options
$psise.Options.ConsolePaneForegroundColor
```

... when using cmldets that don't have color like Write-Output, which is pipeline friendly. You can create your own GUI message boxes/forms to have more control.

Why are you doing this -WhatIf here?

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.Name -Replace $Replace -WhatIf
```

If this is live code, then this Set-* will never happen and thus makes everything below it is moot, because nothing has changed. Unless what you are posting is your test/debug/OpsCheck code, then this is prudent.

You have this ...

```
# Check the attributes value
Get-ADUser -identity $UserInput -Properties $MailProperties |
    Select-Object Name,
                    msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                    msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                    msExchRecipientTypeDetails,
                        (@{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {
                        ($_.proxyAddresses | 
                        Where-Object {($_ -like 'SMTP*') -and 
                        ($_ -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') 
                    } | 
                    Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | 
                    ForEach-Object {$_.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }})
}
```

... shown twice. Just make it a separate function and call it as needed

So, the below is untested, since I am not anywhere near a lab to try this.

***Note:***

I am using PowerShell's natural line breaks to ensure code readability and not be so long.

There are times when long lines cannot be avoided, but whenever possible, if your code line won't fit on a normal 8.5x11.5 sheet of paper like a normal Word doc or book, then it is too long and a target for refactoring, using natural line breaks, splatting, hash tables, PSCustomerObjects, etc.

**Refactored code: Again, I am not in my AD/Exchange lab environment, so I useg Localuser cmdlets** for a quick and dirty code test.

***(personally I'd put this is a single user form using the PowerShell Help and avoid all the menuing stuff altogether - see this: [Poor Man’s GUI](https://powershell.getchell.org/2018/02/13/poor-mans-gui)*** or create a custom form using https://poshgui.com.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'

<# 
Using PowerShell StrictMode Option force code compliance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7
#>

$UserInput              = $null
$ADUser                 = $null
$MailProperties         = $null
$ADUserAttributesValues = $null
$MenuCaption            = $null
$MenuMessage            = $null
$Menu                   = $null
$MenuChoices            = $null
$UserAnswer             = $null
$choice                 = $null
$MenuChoices            = $null
$MenuCaption            = $null 
$MenuMessage            = $null  
$MenuChoices            = $null 
$ReplaceValue           = $null

Function Get-ADAttributesValue
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('gaav')]

    Param
    (
    
    )

    # Check the attributes value
    Get-ADUser -identity $UserInput -Properties $MailProperties |
    Select-Object   Name,
                    msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                    msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                    msExchRecipientTypeDetails,
                        (@{Label = 'Email Address'; Expression = {
                        ($PSitem.proxyAddresses | 
                        Where-Object {($PSitem -like 'SMTP*') -and 
                        ($PSitem -notlike '*onmicrosoft.com') 
                    } | 
                    Sort-Object -CaseSensitive -Descending | 
                    ForEach-Object {$PSitem.Split(':')[1]}) -join ', ' }})
}

$MailProperties =  'Name,
                    msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                    msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                    msExchRecipientTypeDetails,
                    proxyAddresses' -split ','

Do
{
    Write-Host -Object 'Enter a samAccountName / Alias "First.Lastname", or nothing (Press Enter) to leave; wildcards and a space-separated list are NOT supported.' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    
    $UserInput = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::
                 InputBox(
                     'Enter the User AD account to check', 
                     'Name / Alias "First.Lastname"', 
                     $UserInput
                 )
    
    If ($UserInput)
    {
        $(ForEach ($Username in $UserInput.Split(' ', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                If ($ADUser = Get-ADuser -Filter { samAccountName -like $UserName } -Properties Name)
                {
                    Write-Verbose -Message "Processing $($ADUser.Name)"
                    Write-Host "The samAccountName $($UserInput) matching to the AD account '$($ADUser.Name)'" -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                Else {Write-Warning -Message "Could not find a user with a samAccountName matching '$($UserName)' !"}
            })
    }
}
Until (-not $UserInput)



If (!(Get-Module "*ActiveDirectory*"))
 {
    Try { Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop }
    Catch 
    { 
        Write-Warning "Unable to load Active Directory module because $($Error[0])"
        Exit 
    }
}


$UserInput = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::
         InputBox(
             'Enter the User AD account to check', 
             'Name / Alias "First.Lastname"', 
             $UserInput
         )


$ADUserAttributesValues = Get-ADUser -identity $Input -Properties $properties |
                            Select-Object Name,
                                          msExchRemoteRecipientType,
                                          msExchRecipientDisplayType,
                                          msExchRecipientTypeDetails

$MenuCaption = "Hybrid AD User account Exchange attribute modification"
$MenuMessage = "Please select the action to be applied to the user $($UserInput) `n $($ADUserAttributesValues)"
        ## Format: "Menu Text" = "Help Text"
        ## "Menu Text" must match the options in the Switch statement below
        ## "&" marks the character to use as hotkey

$Menu = [ordered]@{
    'Remote &Shared Mailbox' = "Convert $($UserInput) as Remote Shared Mailbox"
    'Remote &User Mailbox'   = "Convert $($UserInput) as Remote User Mailbox"
    '&Quit'                  = 'Leave without changes'
}

$MenuChoices = @()

$Menu.Keys | 
ForEach-Object {
    $choice             =  [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]$PSitem
    $choice.HelpMessage =  $Menu[$PSitem]
    $MenuChoices        += $choice
}

$UserAnswer = $host.UI.PromptForChoice(
    $MenuCaption , 
    $MenuMessage , 
    $MenuChoices, 
    ($Menu.Count - 1)
)

Switch ($MenuChoices[$UserAnswer].Label) 
{
    'Remote &Shared Mailbox' {
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "You selected to convert $($UserInput) as Remote Shared Mailbox" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        # Set The attributes value for Remote Shared Mailboxes
        $ReplaceValue = @{
            msExchRemoteRecipientType  = 100
            msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
            msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 34359738368
        }

        # Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.Name -Replace $ReplaceValue -WhatIf
        Get-ADAttributesValue
}

    'Remote &User Mailbox' {
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "You selected to convert $($UserInput) as Remote User Mailbox" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        
        # Set The attributes value for Remote Regular User Mailboxes
        $ReplaceValue = @{
            msExchRemoteRecipientType  = 4
            msExchRecipientDisplayType = -2147483642
            msExchRecipientTypeDetails = 2147483648
        }

        # Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUserAttributesValues.Name -Replace $ReplaceValue -WhatIf        
        Get-ADAttributesValue
    }
    default 
    {
        Write-Host 'Goodbye' -ForegroundColor Green
        Exit
    }
}
```

***Update***

As for:

> "the script above you've submitted stuck in the Do Until (-not
> $UserInput) loop :-) "

As does yours.    ;-}

Be sure to pay attention to when to use assignment operators '=' vs comparison operators '-eq'.

Simply, that is because that is what you wrote it to do. I did not address that part as that was not part of your request. Your code specifically will not exit until you pass it an empty string. The input will always be equal.

So, if you are saying it should exit if the name is not found or the like then that is what you have to add to your code.  Also, you are using -Like and that needs a wildcard string, otherwise use -eq.

In that 'get request', you should pipe to select-object -Properties or use dot property.

Also, you are instructing the user to only enter one name, but your code is looking for an array. Why?

Lastly in your 'get request', you are only asking for one property, so no others are available, so, there is no need for the Dot property later.

So, I'd refactor the do loop this way...

***(Again, there are other ways (like Try/Catch/Finally with or without the Begin/Process/End blocks)***

... this is just one.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic

$MsgText = '
Enter a sAMAccountName / Alias as First.Lastname
Wildcards and a space-separated list are NOT supported.
To quit, enter nothing and click OK.'

$d = [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::show($MsgText, 'User Instrutions',
     [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo, 
     [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)

Do
{
    $UserInput = $null

    If ($d -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Yes)
    {
        # Show inputbox for user to enter a single username
        $UserInput = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::
        InputBox(
                    'Enter the User AD account to check', 
                    'sAMAccountName / Alias "First.Lastname"', 
                    $UserInput
                )    
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Warning -Message 'You decided to exit the requested action'
        Break
    }
    
    # ForLoop??? --- Why are you checking for an array, when you are only asking for one entry at a time?

    If ($UserInput -eq (Get-LocalUser | Where-Object Name -eq $UserInput))
    {Write-Host "Processing $UserInput" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow}
    Else{Write-Warning -Message "Could not find a user with a Name matching $UserInput ! Try again."}
}
Until (-not $UserInput)

# Results when cancelling the instructions box
<#
WARNING: You decided to exit the requested action
#>

# Results from the inputbox
<#
WARNING: Could not find a user with a Name matching test ! Try again.
WARNING: Could not find a user with a Name matching admin ! Try again.
Processing administrator
WARNING: Could not find a user with a Name matching gues ! Try again.
Processing guest
WARNING: Could not find a user with a Name matching  ! Try again.
#>
```

More code is needed to handle the output of the OK/Cancel button, when and if the input is null or cancel is used. For example the Try/Catch I spoke of earlier.

Again popping GUIs, then sending stuff to the console is a very bad user experience. Stay consistent, pick one or the other. Again, us a single GUI form for this, send user instructions and info to the body of that form.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and example, it does make sense. However, the script above you've submitted stuck in the Do Until (-not $UserInput) loop :-)